# HDMI to VGA somehow zooming computer screen in

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

So i recently purchased an Acer AL1916W from a garage sale (about 50 cents) and I planned to use it as a dual monitor to my computer (with an Staples-branded HDMI to VGA converter as my computer does not have a second VGA port). It worked fine for a while until I accidentally set it to a different resolution than its native 1440x900, and so now when I set it back the screen is very noticeably zoomed in (as in, the taskbar is only halfway visible and you cannot see to the right of the minimize button, i have windows). I was wondering if i could do anything about this? And what makes it even weirder is the fact that upon checking the "Info" section of the monitors menu, it originally said it was a 1440x900 resolution but now it says its 1400x1050. Also when i plug the computer in directly to the monitor it works fine (to be expected), and the same when i reverse it (plugging the first monitor into the HDMi converter, second into the VGA) it also works fine (my first is an Acer E202HL).

edit 9/13: so its working fine now but only when on the "extend" mode, any other mode (duplicate, second screen only, etc) has the same problem described before

Comment: What adapter are you using?

Comment: The Staples-branded one (it was the only one I could find in store, also sorry for the late response).

Comment: Your adapter is likely acting up depending on whenever it's active or not. If the native resolution is 1440x900 and it was running at 1400x1050 it would explain the "zoomed in".

Comment: How would i possibly change the "active" status of the adapter or set the monitor back to 1440x900?